# Where to store log files thay may be generated from both a low-integrity process and a Windows Service?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, logging

**In short:** Is there a **standard** folder in Windows that is 1) writable by **low-integrity** processes 2) **independent of the user** running the process?

---

There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow about the location of log files, but I think my problem is a wee bit different.

My application has two main components: an ActiveX, which runs under IE and has thus low integrity, and a Windows Service.  Both of them generate logs, and I would like to store everything in the same place.

I tried using `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow)`. That's just fine for the ActiveX, but Windows returns the following folder for my service: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\`. That's bad for a number of reasons.

I can't use `%AllUsersProfile%` or %APPDATA% either, because low-integrity processes don't have write permission there.

I've thought about having my service find out the currently logged on user and manually get to the LocalLow folder, but there can be 0 or many of those, so that'd also be a problem.

Comment: What about the system log? Do you need to write to your own, separate file?

Comment: @Acme: Isn't the temp folder also username-dependent? On my Win7 x64 machine, %temp% equals "C:\Users\pfranco\AppData\Local\Temp".

Comment: @Cody Gray: using the system log would mean rewriting my whole logging infrastructure, so that's a no go.

Answer (score 0):

I would still pick %ALLUSERSPROFILE%.  Under that path, you would typically create a folder for your company name and then a folder for the product.  Regular non-admin user accounts are able to write to %ALLUSERSPROFILE% but for your specific scenario if default ACLs are not good enough, you can always modify the permissions on the directory for your specific application during install time.

We've deployed something very similar to what you have (ActiveX control running within IE as well as a set of services and regular apps) and that's where we store our logs without any problems.